# unknown id - cannot locate it in the context of the component (Already tried using :id but it doesn't work)

Tags: ajax, jsf, render

I have the following:

```
<h:form id="form" >
   <h:panelGroup>
     <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.value}">
     <f:ajax listener="#{bean.test()}" execute="@this" render=":form:modes"/>
   </h:panelGroup>

   <rich:collapsiblePanel id="modes" header="Show/hide" switchType="client">
       ........
   </rich:collapsiblePanel>
</h:form>
```

But I get an error saying  contains an unknown id ':form:modes' - cannot locate it in the context of the component. I have also tried doing render=":modes" but I get the same error.

Comment: Can you just give render="modes" ?

Comment: No. It produces the same error.

Comment: Check your rendered HTML and make sure something is getting rendered with that id. If you haven't read it yet, this answer gives a very thorough overview of id's in ajax calls and including several tricks to resolve the common issues http://stackoverflow.com/a/8644762/2780051

Comment: So the id is being rendered as form:modes on the HTML. Thanks for the link axemoi, but still no luck. I tried doing render="form:modes" & ":form:modes" & ":modes" & "modes" but nothing seems to work

Comment: might be a copy/paste error.. just that the f:ajax tag seems to be missing the "/>" at the end.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was an error when copying my code on stackoverflow. I fixed it.

Comment: can you just cross verify the html produced by viewing the source and checking if the rich:collapsiblePanel  is there with id="modes" correctly ?